There is an error in the non-recursive implementation of the preorder traversal of a binary tree, but there is no problem in debugging
When implementing a preorder traversal of a binary tree using a non-recursive approach, I wrote my own stack. An error occurred during runtime.
When I try to debug and find the problem, it runs normally again. Why is that?
When I copied the contents from .h and .c files into the main program, the problem also disappeared. Why is that?
The development environment is CLion 2024.2+MinGw
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(CLionProjectC11 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(BT BT.c Stack.c)
add_executable(BT2 BT2.c)

stack.h
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef STACK_DATA_T
#define STACK_DATA_T int
#endif  // STACK_DATA_T

typedef struct StackNode {
    STACK_DATA_T data;
    struct StackNode *next;
} Stack, *StackNode;

bool initStack(StackNode stack);

bool isEmptyStack(StackNode stack);

bool pushStack(StackNode stack, STACK_DATA_T data);

STACK_DATA_T popStack(StackNode stack);

#endif //STACK_H


stack.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Stack.h"

bool initStack(StackNode stack) {
    stack->data = 0;
    stack->next = NULL;
    return true;
}

bool isEmptyStack(StackNode stack) {
    return stack->next == NULL;
}

bool pushStack(StackNode stack, STACK_DATA_T data) {
    StackNode node = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (node == NULL) return false;
    node->data = data;
    node->next = stack->next;
    stack->next = node;
    return true;
}

STACK_DATA_T popStack(StackNode stack) {
    if (isEmptyStack(stack)) return false;
    StackNode node = stack->next;
    stack->next = stack->next->next;
    STACK_DATA_T data = node->data;
    free(node);
    return data;
}

BT.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct TreeNode {
    char element;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
} Tree, *TreeNode;

#define STACK_DATA_T TreeNode
#include "Stack.h"

void preOrder(TreeNode root) {
    Stack head;
    initStack(&head);
    while (root || !isEmptyStack(&head)) {
        while (root) {
            printf("%c ", root->element);
            pushStack(&head, root);
            root = root->left;
        }
        root = popStack(&head);
        root = root->right;
    }
}

int main() {
    TreeNode a = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    TreeNode b = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    TreeNode c = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    a->element = 'A';
    b->element = 'B';
    c->element = 'C';
    a->left = b;
    a->right = c;
    b->left = b->right = c->left = c->right = NULL;

    preOrder(a);
    printf("\n");

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
}

BT2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct TreeNode {
    char element;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
} Tree, *TreeNode;

#define STACK_DATA_T TreeNode

typedef struct StackNode {
    STACK_DATA_T data;
    struct StackNode *next;
} Stack, *StackNode;

bool initStack(StackNode stack) {
    stack->data = 0;
    stack->next = NULL;
    return true;
}

bool isEmptyStack(StackNode stack) {
    return stack->next == NULL;
}

bool pushStack(StackNode stack, STACK_DATA_T data) {
    StackNode node = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (node == NULL) return false;
    node->data = data;
    node->next = stack->next;
    stack->next = node;
    return true;
}

STACK_DATA_T popStack(StackNode stack) {
    if (isEmptyStack(stack)) return false;
    StackNode node = stack->next;
    stack->next = stack->next->next;
    STACK_DATA_T data = node->data;
    free(node);
    return data;
}

void preOrder(TreeNode root) {
    Stack head;
    initStack(&head);
    while (root || !isEmptyStack(&head)) {
        while (root) {
            printf("%c ", root->element);
            pushStack(&head, root);
            root = root->left;
        }
        root = popStack(&head);
        root = root->right;
    }
}

int main() {
    TreeNode a = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    TreeNode b = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    TreeNode c = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    a->element = 'A';
    b->element = 'B';
    c->element = 'C';
    a->left = b;
    a->right = c;
    b->left = b->right = c->left = c->right = NULL;

    preOrder(a);
    printf("\n");

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
}

I tried to discover the problem through debugging, but it ran correctly during debugging. I also copied the. h and. c files to the main program, and it ran normally. Why is this?

How did you do the debugging? Did you use a debugger like gdb? Or did you just checked by putting print statements?

stack.h contains:
#ifndef STACK_DATA_T
#define STACK_DATA_T int
#endif  // STACK_DATA_T

BT.c defines STACK_DATA_T to be TreeNode before it includes Stack.h. stack.c does not define STACK_DATA_T before it includes Stack.h.. Therefore, these two files get different declarations of data structures and functions that use  STACK_DATA_T. The behavior resulting from the mismatched declarations is not defined by the C standard. The int used by stack.h is insufficient to represent a pointer, so the pushStack and popStack routines fail to preserve all the bits of the addresses pushed onto and popped from the stack.
BT2.c defines STACK_DATA_T and does not contain the #ifndef code, so it uses TreeNode for STACK_DATA_T throughout.
Modify the code so every translation unit uses the same definition for the stack data type.
